# after build,electron flash can not work

Tags: flash, electron

when i use `npm run dev`, electron flash can work. but i built the program to `.exe` for win10 , the electron flash can not work, how i deal with it?  i use electron-vue frame,this is my electron configuration :

### /src/main/index.js

```
const pepflashplayer = app.getPath('pepperFlashSystemPlugin');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', pepflashplayer);
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-version', '30.0.0.154'); 


mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   height: 563,
   useContentSize: true,
   width: 1250,
   webPreferences:{
     plugins : true
   }
})
```

### src/renderer/components/XX.vue

```
<webview :src="**.swf" plugins autosize
   style="height:100%;margin:0 auto" id="webFlash">
</webview>
```

Comment: Saying that it doesn't work without specifying what specifically is breaking / any errors you're seeing isn't very helpful to people trying to answer your question. Please add as many details as possible about what it is thats not working, what the expected behaviour is, and anything else that might be needed for someone to debug.

Answer (score 0):

> But I built the program to `.exe` for Win 10, the Electron Flash cannot work. 
> How can I deal with it?

I don't use Electron so I don't know if this will solve your problem, but usually you **don't load the SWF file directly** in a Pepper API browser. Try making sure your `src` is an **html** file that itself has code to `embed` the required Flash SWF file.

If `XX.vue` is the one that loads page content...

```
<webview :src="test.html" plugins autosize
   style="height:100%;margin:0 auto" id="webFlash">
</webview>
```

Where the `test.html` code looks something like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <body>
    <embed src="yourFile.swf" width="800" height="600">
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know how it goes.